# jquery - slideUp() stutters or even skips

Tags: jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

I have build in some slideUp()-animations and slideDown()-animations but it stutters and looks like it would even skip the animations.

```
$('#mainDetail').slideUp('slow', function() {

            $('#mainAndSidebar').slideDown('slow', function() {                 
                $('#mainCheckoutMain').load(href, function() {
                    $('#mainCheckoutLoader').slideUp('slow',function() {    
                        alert('l up end');
                        $('#mainCheckoutMain').slideDown('slow');
                    });
                });
            });             
        });
```

the alert() is displayed BEFORE the animation slides up (?)

I cant't help.. I 'm searching and trying for hours now but just can't figure out why that is?

Comment: That could be a css problem too. Please add more details and the full code.

Comment: Try to change the `alert` to `console.log` as it fires immediately when the interpreter reads it and hence you are unable to see your code in action.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar .. that was exact what I wanted .. to see WHEN it is fired.. in my case, after the animation ends

Comment: @eisbehr  .. I cant't share the link because it is on my localhost.. to post the whole code would be too much (i think) .. what do you expect by assuming CSS as the source of this problem?